# React Native slow off-screen transition on android

Tags: android, performance, react-native

On Android, when translating off-screen components onto the screen, it takes a very long time. When the function to bring them on-screen is triggered, it seems to completely block the main thread for (almost a) second. I am only rendering 100 simple elements and iOS can handle it even with a much greater pixel density. On Android, this issue is reproducible for me even on a high end phone.

I have created a minimal repo here: https://github.com/darajava/render-bug-android-react-native

See these 2 videos for a comparison of how Android vs iOS handles it:

Android: https://youtu.be/KBP2HHMzAiU
iOS: https://youtu.be/fw-Prh_9HhY

I created a react native issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30987

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug in RN? If so, is there a workaround I can use?